# How to implement save-to-file-check-overwrite in a vscode extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have to implement a very typical programming pattern in a Visual Studio Code extension: save something to a file, but check if the target file exists before doing so and ask the user if it is ok to overwrite it, if it does.

Usually I would just open a file save dialog to ask the user to give me a file name and this dialog would do all necessary checks and gets the user confirmation, if necessary. In vscode however we don't have a file save dialog (however there is [a feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13807) for it). So I'm trying to implement this with the limited means we have there. Fortunately a few weeks ago a new option parameter was added to message dialogs to allow making them modal. But somehow I can't get the timing right. Here's my code:

```
    window.showInputBox({
        placeHolder: "<Enter full file name here>",
        prompt: "Enter the name to an html file to save the diagram\n" }
    ).then((value: string) => {
        if (value) {
            let canWrite = true;
            if (fs.existsSync(value)) {
                canWrite = false;
                window.showWarningMessage("The specified file exists already", { modal: true }, ...[ "Overwrite" ]).then((action: string) => {
                    if (action === "Overwrite") {
                        canWrite = true;
                    }
                });
            }

            if (canWrite) {
                var stream = fs.createWriteStream(value, { encoding: "utf-8", autoClose: true });
                stream.on("error", function (error: any) {
                    window.showErrorMessage("Could not write to file '" + value + "'. " + error);
                });
                stream.once('open', function (fd) {
                    stream.write(text);
                    stream.end();

                    window.showInformationMessage("Diagram successfully written to file '" + value + "'.");
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

The problem is that the call to `window.showWarningMessage` is non-blocking, that means while the dialog (which itself is modal) opens the code after `if (canWrite)` is already executed. This is not a big issue since `canWrite` is `false` in this moment, however, once the `showWarningMessage` thenable returns no code is executed anymore in the outer thenable (from `showInputBox`), i.e. the `if (canWrite)` is not executed again (as I would expect). Is it impossible to nest 2 thenables or what else am I doing wrong?

How would an experienced typescript/vscode develper approach this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `showWarningMessage` is not thenable as you need, you can't nest it. Instead, you have to create your own Thenable approach, which would require a bit of refactoring.

The main idea is that your **Saving** must return a `Promise`, and it will control the `showWarningMessage` return (when needed)

```
function saveDiagram(text, filename): Promise<string | boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (fs.existsSync(filename)) {
            vscode.window.showWarningMessage("The specified file exists already", { modal: true }, ...[ "Overwrite" ]).then((action: string) => {
                if (action === "Overwrite") {
                    resolve(filename);
                } else {
                    resolve(false);
                }
            });
        } else {
            resolve(filename);
        }
    });
}
```

Also extract your **Writing Diagram on Disk** as a new function, to be called latter:

```
function writeDiagramOnDisk(text, filename) {
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename, { encoding: "utf-8", autoClose: true });
    stream.on("error", function (error: any) {
        vscode.window.showErrorMessage("Could not write to file '" + filename + "'. " + error);
    });
    stream.once('open', function (fd) {
        stream.write(text);
        stream.end();

        vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Diagram successfully written to file '" + filename + "'.");
    });
}
```

And now your extension's code will have the thenable approach, as you would expect:

```
vscode.window.showInputBox({
    placeHolder: "<Enter full file name here>",
    prompt: "Enter the name to an html file to save the diagram\n" }
).then((value: string) => {
    if (value) {
        saveDiagram(text, value)
            .then((filename) => {
                if (filename) {
                    writeDiagramOnDisk(text, filename)
                }
            });

    }
})
```

Comment: Your solution makes sense and I may use it in the future. For now I have simply moved my save code to a separate function and call that either directly or once I found an existing file and the user agreed to overwrite it.